# Redirecting all urls, including no path, to a file in subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have checked a large amount of existing answers regarding `.htaccess` redirects. However none of them have helped me.

What I want to accomplish is redirecting all request urls to `/api/init.php`. However I've only gotten so far to where my index page `www.example.com` simply gives me a file listing because of the missing `index.php` file, while every url request with a path is working.

How can I accomplish this with `.htaccess` without ending up with a directory listing on my landing page?

**This is as far as I got:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /api/init.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well your site root is a directory, so this rule you have excludes existing directories. What you could do is only exclude existing files, and allow existing directories to be handled by the PHP script. Like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/api/init.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /api/init.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I removed the `NC` flag as it's not needed. I added a condition to prevent an unnecessary file-system check.

You don't have to pass the path on in a URL parameter, as you could get it from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in PHP (not the same as `REQUEST_URI` in mod_rewrite, in PHP it always has the original URI). If you wanted to do that then your rule becomes nice and simple:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/api/init.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /api/init.php [L]
```

Because the query string will just be passed on unaffected (so `QSA` is not needed).

Comment: "to prevent an unnecessary iteration" - or rather an _unnecessary file system check_. Good answer +1

Comment: @user82217 Yes agreed, have changed that. Glad you like it :)

Comment: This works great :) and also thanks for the tip about the `NC` flag